# JavaScript is concatenating instead of adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using these in my code:

```
alert(mult);  //1.114
alert(profit);  //10
price = (mult * profit) + profit;
alert(price);  //11.14 should be 21.14
```

I also tried `price = ((mult*profit) + profit);` but got the same result. Instead of doing `(1.114*10) + 10;` it is doing `1.114*10=11.14`. It is not adding the additional 10 at the end.

Comment: The `+` operator concatenates its arguments if you give it a string. That means either `mult` or `profit` is a string. Use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` to turn a string into a number.

Comment: This isn't concatenation.  It's doing the multiplication without adding (or concatenating).  If it was concatenating, the result would be `"11.1410"`.  Execute this in the console: `'1.114' * '10' + '10'`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Voting to close the question. @raulxbox please edit your question to include a **Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable example**.

Comment: Are you sure it alert `11.14` and not `11.1410`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are probably strings, use `parseFloat` to convert them to numbers :

```
mult = parseFloat(mult);
profit = parseFloat(profit);
price = (mult*profit) + profit
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: it works but it is not taking decimal values it shows 21.00 not 21.14

Comment: @raulxbox use parseFloat() as in the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me like this.  It doesn't seem that concatenation is an issue, because otherwise the value would be '11.1410'.

```js
var mult = 1.114;
var profit = 10;
var price = (mult*profit) + profit;
alert(price);//11.14 should be 21.14
```

If the `profit` variable (or both variables) is a string, the result would be "11.1410".

```js
var mult = 1.114;
    var profit = '10';
    var price = (mult*profit) + profit;
    alert(price);//11.1410
```

The result seems unaffected if just the `mult` value is a string.

```js
 var mult = '1.114';
        var profit = 10;
        var price = (mult*profit) + profit;
        alert(price);//21.14
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that either `mult` or `profit` are of type `string` and not of type `number`. This can be fixed by explicitly casting.

You can determine the type of your variables in your browser console (i.e. dev tools) with the `typeof` keyword like this:

```
typeof foo
```

If either of your variables are of type `string` you can convert them to `number` with [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
mult = parseFloat(mult);
```

Comment: typeof mult 
"undefined"
typeof profit
"object"
this is what I get in console

Comment: Try running those commands while at a debugger breakpoint, or just execute those lines of code with a `console` statement

Comment: I tried and its working mult = parseFloat(mult); but it is not taking decimal points it shows 21.00 not 21.14

Comment: You may need to `parseFloat` both variables

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this is in the chrome js console `F12` key.

```
var mult = 1.114, profit = 10;
console.log('mult=', mult);//1.114
console.log('profit=', profit);//10
price = (mult*profit) + profit;
console.log('price=', price);//11.14 should be 21.14
```

And got these results

```
mult= 1.114
profit= 10
price= 21.14
```